# Can the Bayes factor be negative?

Tags: bayesian, inference

This is what I saw in a source I am referring to:

[image]

Since both the numerator and the denominator are probabilities (so they can only take any value between 0 and 1), how can the result of division be negative?

Comment: This isn't saying Negative in the sense of a negative number < 0 -- indeed, the Range column just says < 1. It means negative in the more logical sense of being evidence against a hypothesis rather than for -- Positive/Negative evidence, For/Against, Pro/Contra, etc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not sure what your source is, but whoever it is seems to have botched [Harold Jeffreys' cutoffs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor#Interpretation). The items in the table *do* match his recommendations, but with two problems. The first is that the cutoffs are intended to be for $\log \text{BF}$ rather than for the Bayes factor itself (**EDIT:** slightly misspoke, the unit is "decihartleys" which corresponds to $10 \log_{10}(\text{BF})$). The second is that, probably because the person who put the table together didn't realize the scale was suppose to be $\log$, they "corrected" the first row to be $< 1$ instead of $< 0$ because they assumed $< 0$ must be a typo (since Bayes factors can't be negative).